# Inserting data from PK to FK and inserting resource-id of a data to another table using its resource-name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Really a beginner at php. Any help or insight would really be appreciated and will be up voted. Thanks!

So I want to insert the data from the PK which is transaction_id which is auto incremented from the table transactions to the FK on the transaction_line table. And i want to insert the resource_id as well to transaction_line.

[image]

So when I submit a form, it will get the resource_name. I want to display the resource_id to the transaction line from the table resources and not the resource_name.

Tried the query;

```
INSERT INTO `transaction_line`(`transaction_id`, `resource_id`) VALUES (transactions.transaction_id,(SELECT resource_id FROM resources WHERE resource_id = resources.resource_id));
```

But I get errors and not sure about that query really. Please help!

[image]

For Kabir Safi.

```
$equipment = $_POST['equipment'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM resources;";
$con = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if ($con->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
        if (strcmp($equipment, $row['resource_name']) == 0) {
            $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
            var_dump($last_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use insert last id

Comment: It does not work sir. Tried to var_dump it and it shows int(0)

Comment: show your quries

Comment: @KabirSafi Just posted the code I used that will output int(0)

Comment: $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);   after mysqli_query  and remove all other code

Comment: $query = "inser into resources;";
$con = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);